# Need help with a basic proof using Paeno Axioms showing that a recursively defined function is one to one

Tags: analysis, peano-axioms

Assume $(N, 0_N, ++^N) and (N˜, 0_{N˜} , ++^{N˜} )$ are two systems satisfying the Peano
axioms.

Define the function

$T : N → N˜$
by

$T(0_N) = 0_{N˜}$

and

$T(n++^N) = T(n)++^{N˜}$

Prove that
T(n) = T(m) ⇒ n = m

I can't figure out how to close my proof by induction. First I proved the proposition that $ n \neq 0$ implies there exists a m such that m++ = n. Which I then used to prove that for n = $0$ , T(n) = T(m) implies n = m = $0_N$ (using the axiom that $0$ is not a successor and proving the contrapositive) . Now for the inductive step I'm trying to prove that (T(n) = T(m) => n=m) => (T(n++) = t(m) => n++=m) and I can't figure it out for the life of me how to get there. Can somebody please point me in the right direction? Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $++$ is a unary function symbol which is interpreted as the successor function in the standard model. For the sake of clarity, I will replace it with a prefix unary function $S$ (so that my $Sx$ is the same as your $x++$).

*(incorrect answer removed)*

After I came back home and reflected on the question, I think that it's important to emphasize that the problem statement is only true assuming that we are using second-order Peano axioms, in which every subset of the universe which contains $0^N$ and is closed under $S^N$ is equal to the whole universe. If we only take the first-order Peano axioms then this will **not** be true. To see this, let $N$ be a model of cardinality $\alpha\ge\aleph_0$ (e.g. the standard model $(\mathbb{N},0,x\mapsto x+1)$) and apply upward Löwenheim-Skolem-Tarski Theorem to get a model $N^\prime$ of cardinality $\beta>\alpha$. Then the problem statement would say that there exists an injection $N^\prime\to N$, which implies that $\beta\le\alpha$, which is absurd. Then it should be fairly simple, even trivial, to show that the statement holds in second-order arithmetic. (See comment for details)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't have much experience with proofs and I am a bit confused as it appears we are inducting on n and m. IE we are proving that T(S(n)) = T(S(m)) => S(n) = S(m). Is this sort of thing allowed? From the way I understand induction shouldn't I have to prove that for all m, by assuming T(n) = T(m) implies n = m it can be shown that for all m T(S(n)) = T(m) implies S(n) = m? Thanks again.

Comment: @mck619 You are right, I don't think the answer I stated is quite correct. However, confer my new paragraph dealing with what level of Peano arithmetic (first- or second-order) we are considering. It seems that we are actually doing second-order arithmetic here, so I think that one can simply say that $\{S^{(n)}0\}_{n\in\omega}$ is a subset containing $0$ and closed under $S$, hence the whole universe. Then every element is of the form $S^{(n)}0$, so just fold out all the $S$'s by definition of $T$ and the theorem holds easily.